# extract clob value from table and store that in xml domdocument oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, domdocument, oracle-xml-db

```
FOR get_rows IN DF_ROWS LOOP
  row_elmt := xmldom.createElement(doc, 'ROW');
  row_node := xmldom.appendChild(root_node, xmldom.makeNode(row_elmt));
  item_elmt := xmldom.createElement(doc, 'COUNTRY_ID');
  item_node := xmldom.appendChild(row_node, xmldom.makeNode(item_elmt));
  item_text := xmldom.createTextNode(doc, get_rows.country_id);
  item_node := xmldom.appendChild(item_node, xmldom.makeNode(item_text));
  item_elmt := xmldom.createElement(doc, 'COUNTRY_NAME');
  item_node := xmldom.appendChild(row_node, xmldom.makeNode(item_elmt));
  item_text := xmldom.createTextNode(doc, get_rows.country_name);
  item_node := xmldom.appendChild(item_node, xmldom.makeNode(item_text));
  item_elmt := xmldom.createElement(doc, 'REGION_ID');
  item_node := xmldom.appendChild(row_node, xmldom.makeNode(item_elmt));
  item_text := xmldom.createTextNode(doc, get_rows.region_ide);
  item_node := xmldom.appendChild(item_node, xmldom.makeNode(item_text));
END LOOP;
```

In above example:

```
item_text := xmldom.createTextNode(doc, get_rows.region_ide);
```

Instead of adding `textnode` I want to add an xml data which I extracted from table. How would I be able to add that?

Comment: help needed on above !!

Comment: got one more issue...can we add a value being returned from a function here??